# My excel is missing pivot table in the ribbon

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table, ribbon

Here is how my excel ribbon looks like:[image: my ribbon]

How can I add pivot table to it?

Regards,

Comment: Click on Insert, should be the left most option on that tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use the Tab "Insert" and you find a Group "Tables". 
If you like to have it on the home tab, you can modify your ribbon. Right-click on the ribbon > Modify ribbon...